# bash: name a file based on two environment variables

Tags: bash

In my bash script, I want to name a file based on two environment variables, which may change based on user setting. For example, I have:

```
JOB_NAME=some_job
DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

and I hope to name my file:

```
FILE_NAME=$JOB_NAME_$DATE.log
```

i.e I hope the file name would look like: some_job_201502021544.log

However, the file name shows 201502021544.log.

Could you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The trailing `_` is included in the variable name, so it is looking for "$JOB_NAME_" which doesn't exist and so you get an empty string. You can delimit with curly brackets i.e. `FILE_NAME="${JOB_NAME}_${DATE}.log"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the first variable in curly braces:

```
FILE_NAME=${JOB_NAME}_$DATE.log
```